# The equivalent verbs which are used when clothes are on your body

Tags: verb-usage

Do the sentences in each group bellow mean the same and can one swap them with each other?

> **1)**
>
> - What are you wearing now?
> - What are you dressed in now?
> - What do you have on now?
>
> **2)**
>
> - He was wearing a tie yesterday.
> - He was dressed in a tie yesterday.
> - He had a tie on yesterday.
> - He had on a tie yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Canadian Eng here.  I find all responses acceptable, and have used and heard them all, so perhaps this is a dialect difference between Can and UK.  Agree about 2 b though, to say 'is dressed in' tends to have a sense of completeness.  In other words, if I ask what someone was dressed in, I expect a response like "A blue business suit, white shirt and tie", not just "a tie".  Hence the humourous (Am Eng readers: note the spelling with the extra 'u' proving Canada bridges the AM-UK divide :) overtones.

Comment: +1 for clearly describing the difference between "wear" and "be dressed in".

Answer (score 2):

1 a & c are fine.
1b is OK, if less common.

2 a & c are again, perfectly acceptable.
2 b has a small possibility for misinterpretation, if only for comedic effect - that he was wearing only a tie, nothing else.
2 d doesn't work for me at all. There may be some colloquial, historical or regional reasoning behind it, but I'd avoid it generally.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, but I would appreciate it if an AmE speaker could put an opinion here as well. I thought that 'dress in' is the most common way convey such a meaning!
Perhaps as you mentioned, there may be some regional differences.

Comment: I would be thankful if you could tell me more about the reason why the versions 'b' can cause some misinterpretations?

Comment: Sure - I'm UK Eng, so there may be some differences. 2d, btw, would be a common form in some UK dialects, but I wouldn't recommend it as 'international english'

Comment: 2b just has amusing overtones. Though not in any way incorrect, it would prompt jokey responses. It brings to mind the recent question [which I can't find just now] "When I come home from work, I change" The first response to which was, "into what? A werewolf?"  It's just too tempting to intentionally take the wrong meaning, it's a big part of certainly british humour.

Comment: Ahah, I understand you well now. I guess it can remind some comedies to the hearer. However, thank you very much for being of this great help Tetsujin. :)

Comment: Oh, I would be thankful if you could answer this question as well Tetsujin; I think as you thought me, the following version 'A' sounds awkward or possibly incorrect too; please consider it: (---A--- I didn’t recognize him because he had an orange suit on. ---)
(---B--- I didn’t recognize him because he had on an orange suit. ---) ==> Do you confirm it?

Comment: For the same reasoning as 2d, 'had an orange suit on' always. The other is either plain 'wrong' or too regional; I would never use it for international english.